# format data in the DataGridView control

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
OleDbDataAdapter Buscar = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT ...", conexao);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
Buscar.Fill(dt);
OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

bSource.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
sda.Update(dt);

private void dataGridView1_DefaultCellStyleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.dataGridView1.Columns[4].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "HH:mm";
}
```

Information comes from datagridview database conversion wanted it to `HH:mm`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use format as "T"?

Suggest to check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-17

Best,

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic example but, it works just as you are wanting it to:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataGridView.Rows.Add(dt);
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "HH:mm";
```

When I run the app, it returns "14:20" or, "HH:mm" as you are expecting.

**EDIT:**

Based on comments below, the OP has stated that he misstated his actual need so, I am updating this answer with code that will reformat the date (but leaving the original code as well for thoroughness).

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataGridView.Rows.Add(dt);
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "T";

    foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
    {
       column.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "HH:mm";
    }
}
```

OP, please note that your loops will likely differ from mine so, keep that in mind.  And just so that you can see exactly the approach I took to vet this out, I will post all of the code as well:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
   using System;
   using System.Windows.Forms;

   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
         {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataGridView.Rows.Add(dt);
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "T";

            foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
            {
                column.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "HH:mm";
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: ![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Etr0v.png

Wanted to take the date of the read only wanted to leave hours

Comment: If you wanted the date, why did you say hours in your question?

Comment: So, do you want to remove the dates and just leave the hours in the rows then?  (Just to be clear since I will have to edit my answer.)

Comment: Yes remove dates leaving only the hours

Comment: @Fellipe Pires - I have updated my answer.  Please take a look.